# Solve $\int\frac{2x-3}{(x^2+x+1)^2}dx$

Tags: integration

$\int\frac{2x-3}{(x^2+x+1)^2}dx$

---

$\int\frac{2x-3}{(x^2+x+1)^2}dx=\int\frac{2x+1}{(x^2+x+1)^2}dx-\int\frac{4}{(x^2+x+1)^2}dx$
First integral is easily integrable but substituting $x^2+x+1=t$ but i cannot integrate the second integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

As $x^2+x+1=\dfrac{(2x+1)^2+3}4,$  set $2x+1=\sqrt3\tan t$

Answer (score 3):

$$\dfrac{d\left(\dfrac{ax^2+bx+c}{x^2+x+1}\right)}{dx}=\dfrac{(2ax+b)(x^2+x+1)-(ax^2+bx+c)(2x+1)}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$$

The numerator $(2ax+b)(x^2+x+1)-(ax^2+bx+c)(2x+1)=x^2(a-b)+x(2a+2c)+b-c$

If the numerator $2x-3,$

$a-b=0\iff a=b$

$b-c=-3\iff c=b+3$

$2(a+c)=2\iff1=a+c=b+b+3\iff b=-1$